# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll'?

Tags: php, iis, composer-php, iis-express

Because I already use ASP.NET I decided to use PHP on IIS, I install it using Wep  PI but when I trying to install Composer he fails with PHP settings error.

I tried to change the extension_dir to absolute and uncommented php_wincache extension in php.ini  but none of my solutions works

> C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.2\php.exe
>
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.2\php.ini
>
> A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.
>
> Program Output:
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_wincache.dll (%1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.), C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_php_wincache.dll.dll (Le module spécifié est introuvable.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon Learn how to use such tools. Also notice what is the bitness of your PHP installation and WOW64 redirection can contribute to such issues. That's why people always prefer to use C:\php

Answer (score 4):

It's a little late to answer this question. But I also face the same issue and somehow able to resolve it. Please follow below steps to resolve this.

Step 1: Install Windows Cache Extension for PHP.

```
    You can install it from http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.installation.php
    Or you can use Web Platform Installer. (Please see the screenshot.)
```

[image]

Step 2: After installation goes to folder "Windows Cache for PHP". Copy php_wincache.dll.

[image]

Step 3: Paste copied file into your PHP/ext location. e.g. "C:/Program Files/PHP/v7.0/ext".

[image]

Now you can try to install composer again.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have that same problem when I updated my Php version. I already downloaded the  `wincache.dll` and paste it to my ext file but it still throw this error  `'Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll'` @rajk

Comment: Nice - thanks. I used Web PI to install the Windows Cache Extension for PHP (not IIS) and it installed straight to PHP without needing to copy the DLL. Make sure you choose the correct bitness (x86 or x64).

Comment: As of December 31st, 2022, Web Platform Installer is no more.
https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed
Launching Web Platform Installer will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and found the answer on [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wincache.installation.php).

> The wincache version for 7.0 is compiled for php7.dll not the thread
>   safe php7ts.dll.  You may need to compile the source for wincache or
>   change to the non thread safe version.

Guess is you have installed the "thread safe" version of PHP, and you don't have php7.dll which WinCache needs.