# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll'

Tags: php, iis

I have installed wincache. i followed the link and installed wincache.dll. the link is given below. [Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538107/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-wincache-dll)

Before installation the error was.
"[03-Jun-2020 12:00:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (tried: C:\PHP\ext\php_wincache.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\PHP\ext\php_php_wincache.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0"

After Installation iam getting.
"[04-Jun-2020 07:40:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (tried: C:\PHP\ext\php_wincache.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\PHP\ext\php_php_wincache.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0"

This is a laravel application on IIS server. please suggest what to do

The configuration of the system is given.

windows server 2016 standard 64-bit , IIS 10 , wincache-2.0.0.8-dev-7.4-nts-vc15-x86 , php 7.4.4 is installed on the server and laravel version is 5.8. These re the configurations please suggest. –

Comment: Please share your configuration, like: which version of PHP and Wincache you are using

Comment: This error has a lot to do with your PHP version and windows server version. It seems that whether to install php_wincache has nothing to do with the error.
In order to run a laravel application on IIS server, please refer to the below links.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640159/how-can-i-setup-an-laravel-project-on-iis-7-5
https://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/

Comment: https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/installing-laravel-4-in-windows-7-with-iis7/
https://www.phpsync.com/2016/10/laravel-5-installing-windows-IIS.html

Comment: windows server 2016 standard 64-bit , IIS 10 , wincache-2.0.0.8-dev-7.4-nts-vc15-x86 , php 7.4.4 is installed on the server and laravel version is 5.8. These re the configurations please suggest.